# MPI Allreduce error on MPICH 3.1.5 on ARMv7

Tags: c, mpi, distributed-computing

I have a small cluster of four Raspberry Pi 2 Model Bs. I'm using them to experiment with distributed computing.

I have some code on Github: https://github.com/gordon1992/RPI-Cluster-Scratch

hello_world_c functions fine. global_sum_c (and _f95) error, with the below output:

```
pi@rpi-cluster-1 ~/RPI-Cluster-Scratch/global_sum_c $ ./run.sh 
Assertion failed in file src/mpi/coll/helper_fns.c at line 491: status->MPI_TAG == recvtag
internal ABORT - process 0

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 26572 RUNNING AT rpi-cluster-1
=   EXIT CODE: 1
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
[proxy:0:2@rpi-cluster-3] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:886): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:2@rpi-cluster-3] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:2@rpi-cluster-3] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[proxy:0:3@rpi-cluster-4] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:886): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:3@rpi-cluster-4] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:3@rpi-cluster-4] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[proxy:0:1@rpi-cluster-2] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:886): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:1@rpi-cluster-2] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:1@rpi-cluster-2] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@rpi-cluster-1] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:76): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@rpi-cluster-1] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@rpi-cluster-1] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:218): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@rpi-cluster-1] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:336): process manager error waiting for completion
```

I'm using gcc v4.9.2 and MPICH 3.1-5 (installed from Debian testing repositories).

The code runs fine if I only execute it over a single device (say rpi-cluster-1) but not when over multiple devices.

I'm somewhat confused as to what the problem could be, especially since MPI_COMM_WORLD is an intra-communicator and MPI_In_Place is only invalid for inter-communicators.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I get the same assertion failed on a CentOS 6.8 virtual-machine cluster when I call MPI_Comm_spawn; in my case it fails in the spawned worker's MPI_Init. Using diff to compare the source code of mpich's MPIC_Sendrecv function between versions 3.1 and 3.2 shows the block containing that assert was removed in 3.2 but this doesn't seem to be mentioned in mpich's bug-tracking system. The code I'm trying to maintain also fails in OpenMPI with Error 16, and I haven't managed to install MPICH 3.2 on the CentOS 6.8. Would be nice if MPI's error messages were a bit more descriptive of the real problem.

Comment: One problem we found in our setup was that the /etc/hosts files on each node were not resolving 127.0.0.1 to "localhost".  They'd given them actual node names instead.  Fixing this caused the above assertion failure to go away in our case.  I don't know if OP had the same issue.